# SonarQube - Custom rule to prevent call to some static methods

Tags: java, sonarqube

I use SonarQube for a Java project.

I want to have a violation when a given static method from a library is used.

Is there a way to do that in the UI, or shall I resort to custom java code as described in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/ ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [squid:S2253](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2253), which is a template rule, to set up a rule that raises an issue when your method is called.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Works fine for `main` code but not for `test` code. Is there any chance such a rule gets picked up for test code ?

Comment: There's not @rcomblen. Not currently. But that is on our list.